# Why i am not able to do console.log in this case and here if i return temps why function is not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, return-value, console.log

```
const calcTempAmplitudeNew = function (t1, t2) {
    const temps = t1.concat(t2);
    //   console.log(temps);
    return temps;
    //if i return temps why function is not working??
    let max = temps[0];
    let min = temps[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
        const curTemp = temps[i];
        if (typeof curTemp !== 'number') continue;
        if (curTemp > max) max = curTemp;
        if (curTemp < min) min = curTemp;
    }
    console.log(max, min);
    return max - min;

};

const amplitudeNew = calcTempAmplitudeNew([3, 5, 1], [9, 0, 5]);
console.log(temps, amplitudeNew);
```

Why i am not able to do console.log in this case??

Answer (score 0):

`temps` in the `console.log()` is being used out of scope. The variable is in the local scope of the function, so you won't be able to use it outside of the function.

if you declare...

```
var temps = ''
```

outside of your function in the first line of code and remove the declaration of `temps` in your function, you can log it outside of the function, as it is now in a global scope.

[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/paulmartin91/pen/MWpqgxg?editors=1011)

[Some More information on scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do so. You have declared the temps variable inside function scoping so that's why the temps are not getting the reference.

```
let temps = []
const calcTempAmplitudeNew = function (t1, t2) {

temps = t1.concat(t2);

console.log(temps);

let max = temps[0];

let min = temps[0];

for (let i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {

const curTemp = temps[i];

if (typeof curTemp !== 'number') continue;



if (curTemp > max) max = curTemp;

if (curTemp < min) min = curTemp;

}
console.log(max, min);

return max - min;
};

const amplitudeNew = calcTempAmplitudeNew([3, 5, 1], [9, 0, 5]);
console.log(temps)
console.log(amplitudeNew);
```